# Looping through a set of variables sharing the same prefix

Tags: macros, spss

I routinely work with student exam files, where each response to an exam item is recorded in points. I want to transform that variable into 1 or 0 (effectively reducing each item to Correct or Incorrect).

Every dataset has the same nomenclature, where the variable is prefixed with `points_` and then followed by an identification number (e.g., `points_18616`). I'm using the following syntax:

```
RECODE points_18616 (0=Copy) (SYSMIS=SYSMIS) (ELSE=1) INTO Binary_18616.
VARIABLE LABELS  Binary_18616 'Binary Conversion of Item_18616'.
EXECUTE.
```

So I end up creating this syntax for each variable, and since every dataset is different, it gets tedious. Is there a way to loop through a dataset and perform this transformation on all variables that are prefixed with `points_`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it:

First I'll create a little fake data to demonstrate on:

```
data list list/points_18616 points_18617 points_18618 points_18619 (4f2).
begin data
4 5 6 7
5 6 7 8
6 7 8 9
7 8 9 9
end data.

* the following code will create a list of all the relevant variables in a new file.
SPSSINC SELECT VARIABLES MACRONAME="!list" /PROPERTIES  PATTERN = "points_*".

* now we'll use the created list in a macro to loop your syntax over all the vars.    
define !doList ()
!do !lst !in(!eval(!list))
RECODE !lst (0=Copy) (SYSMIS=SYSMIS) (ELSE=1) INTO !concat("Binary", !substr(!lst,7)).
VARIABLE LABELS  !concat("Binary", !substr(!lst,7))  !concat("'Binary Conversion of Item",!substr(!lst,7) ,"'.").
!doend
!enddefine.

!doList.
EXECUTE.
```

Comment: eli-k, I don't know how you figure this stuff out. I was testing the syntax on some files and it works---but I found out that I also have variables that are only shorter: points_1234 instead of points_12345. I could just modify your macro and run it twice (it will just throw a few errors), but is there a way to modify your syntax to catch both types of variables? 

I can post as a new question if necessary. Can't thank you enough, this already saves me tons of time!

Comment: No problem - see the edited macro definition, it will now take care of any length of the number code (as long as prefix is the same)

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to comment just to say thanks, but this is a huge help and it works perfectly!